# Calling functions in razorengine

Tags: c#, razorengine

I am using http://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/ to generate strings from a template and am having trouble calling functions within the template. The documentation on the site is a bit lacking with examples, but I am trying to call the `double` ToString function with a format. The format string is:

```
"The value of sensor @Model.Measurement.Sensor.Description is out of spec with a value of ((double)@Model.AdjustedValue).ToString(\"#.##\")"
```

The last part of the string I would like the output to be rounded to the nearest hundredth, but instead of I am getting the following string:

```
"The value of sensor Test_sensor_1 is out of spec with a value of ((double)78.14215625).ToString("#.##")"
```

Could someone point out the correct syntax for what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `@` is in the wrong place, I think:

```
"The value of sensor @Model.Measurement.Sensor.Description is out of spec with a value of @(((double)Model.AdjustedValue).ToString(\"#.##\"))"
```

Comment: Thanks, that generated the string I was wanting.